# Django create create GET url in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to make get request on the django site page,

```
{% if is_paginated %}
    <div class="pagination">
        <span class="page-links">
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a href="{{ url 'clothes:designer' }}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
            {% endif %}
            <span class="page-current">
                Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
            </span>
            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a href="{{ url 'clothes:designer' }}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

i dont want to hardcode href url
can i create GET request url like {{ url 'page' method='get' **kwargs }}?

i tried to find in django docs, but i have not found

Comment: All hyperlinks are GET.

Comment: Sure, this is how it works: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not correctly using the url tag. You should enclose url in "{% %}" and not "{{ }}". Here the documentation [link for the BuiltIn url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

your code should be like this :

```
    {% if is_paginated %}
    <div class="pagination">
        <span class="page-links">
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a href="{% url 'clothes:designer' %}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
            {% endif %}
            <span class="page-current">
                Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
            </span>
            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a href="{% url 'clothes:designer' %}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

You will automatically have a GET link like "?page=x". For example : "/my-url/clothes/designer/?page=2"